# jQuery, AJAX post Javascript array with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

I have a Javascript variable which is an array (I push strings into it) and I have to send that list back to the server through an AJAX jQuery.POST() method:

```
var user_list = new Array();
user_list.push("42");
var data = { user_list: JSON.stringify(user_list)};
$.post('/accounts/ajax/user_verification/', data)
    .done( my_cb );
```

In the server, I am running Django and try to decode the POST request with the following view:

```
@login_required
def user_verification(request):

    if not request.POST.has_key('user_list'):
        print (__name__ + ', user_verification, raising BadRequest.')
        raise Exception("'user_list' not found as a POST parameter.")

    value = unicode(request.POST['user_list'])
    print (__name__ + ', value, v = ' + value)
    user_list = json.loads(request.body)
```

I get the following output and posterior exception thrown by " json.loads(request.body) ":

```
accounts.ajax, value, v = ["42"]
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Isn't ["42"] a valid JSON array definition with a single element?

Comment: try passing `{"42"}` instead of `["42"]`

Comment: But I am using JSON.stringify(), isn't its output correct?

Comment: try changing the 'key' `user_list` in your JSON structure to something else.
It might causing the problem. Also, to be on the safe side, can you change the JSON to `var data = { "newKey": JSON.stringify(user_list)}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Django, so, this a total guess :D

```
import json
...
value = json.load(request.POST['user_list'])
```

Comment: Yes, I think that it is too late... I made a mistake while passing the arguments to json.load().

Comment: @Ricardo I just realized that there is another function called `loads`, and that you were already using it, so, I was a bit off-topic apparently (one more time) :D Glad if it helped in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely wrong here, but it seems to me that you are trying to decode a wrong thing. If I'm not mistaken, you request.body looks like this:

```
user_list=["42"]
```

and if you try to decode this, you have a problem. So why don't you decode the value from variable value?

```
user_list = json.loads(value)
```